# Google Cloud Monitoring - capture dataflow running time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-monitoring

I have setup an alerting policy to send email if dataflow jobs elapsed time is more than 2 hrs in my GCP project. Below is the MQL of policy:

```
fetch dataflow_job
| metric 'dataflow.googleapis.com/job/elapsed_time'
| group_by 5m, [value_elapsed_time_mean: mean(value.elapsed_time)]
| every 5m
| condition value_elapsed_time_mean > 7200 's'
```

I want to filter out all streaming jobs from this policy. I cannot use job_name as the streaming jobs do not follow specific naming pattern.
Please advise how can I do it.

Comment: This seems like a feature request for the monitoring labels of Dataflow metrics, so I've raised this request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/190035344